# why nginx proxy_pass upstream would not work but proxy_pass https url works

Tags: nginx

1.conf

```
server {
  listen 7070;
  server_name localhost;
  location / {
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_pass https://baidu;
  }
}

upstream baidu {
   server www.baidu.com;
}
```

2.conf

```
server {
  listen 7070;
  server_name localhost;
  location / {
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_pass https://www.baidu.com;
  }
}
```

why 2.conf works, but 1.conf can't proxy pass to https://baidu.com ?

it gets `502 Bad Gateway` errors

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SSL, you have to add port 443 to your server in your upstream directive:
https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/security-controls/securing-http-traffic-upstream/

```
server {
  listen 7070;
  server_name localhost;
  
  location / {
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_pass https://baidu;
  }
}

upstream baidu {
  server www.baidu.com:443;
}
```